# C# console application started in three threads

Tags: .net, multithreading, console-application

A proces (htpd.exe) with 66 threads starts another process (cmd.exe) with 1 thread which starts another process that is my developed C# console application (logger.exe) with 3 threads (as seen in Task manager). I have to log all text coming in to stdin.

I am confused as to why my logger.exe has 3 threads. Who made these threads and why (the C# console application does nothing with threads so far)?

Do the 3 threads share one stdin?